# Two parameter Delegate error

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I have the following code.

```
Delegate Sub WriteLogRtbDelegate(ByVal Texto As String, ByVal _Color As Color)


Private Sub WriteLogRTB(ByVal Texto As String, Optional ByVal TextColor As Color = Nothing)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim Txt As New WriteLogRtbDelegate(AddressOf WriteLogRTB)
        Me.Invoke(Txt, New Object() {Texto}, {TextColor}) '<--- Error here
    Else
    ....
    End If
```

In the Invoke line I get

El objeto de tipo 'System.Object[]' no puede convertirse en el tipo 'System.String'.

Something like

The object type 'System.Object[]' can't be converted in the type 'System.String'.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, Would you correct me please?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: I updated the Post, please re read.Thanks.

Comment: Try the line `Me.Invoke(Txt, New Object() {Texto, TextColor})`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, thanks, thats work ok.

Comment: @E_Blue - Previously you were trying to pass two arrays with one element each and not just one array with two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Me.Invoke(Txt, New Object() {Texto}, {TextColor})
```

You should be able to simply do:

```
Me.Invoke(Txt, Texto, TextColor)
```